# Does perspective distort tool work on a raster image? Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, transform

I noticed that the perspective distort transform tool doesn't work on a raster image in illustrator, only vector? I know there is the perspective grid you can use, but its a bit of a hassle when it's just a little detail just e.g a logo on a van.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You can't perspective distort raster images by default in Illustrator.

But...

Add an Envelope...

- Select the Raster Image (you may need to embed the image)
- `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh`
- 1 row, 1 column
- Hit `Okay`

Then you **can** perspective distort the Envelope (which just contains the raster image).

Don't ask me why this is even necessary.. but it works.

---

Note this also works on live text.. which you also can't perspective distort by default.